# AWS load balancing for a complex scenario

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

We were trying to implement an elastic scaling application on AWS. But currently, due to the complexity of the application process, I have an issue with the current routing algorithm.

In the application when we send a request (a request to a complex calculation). We immediately send a token to the user and start calculating. So the user can return with the token any day and access those calculated results. When there are more calculation requests they will be in a queue and get executed 2 by 2 as one calculation takes a considerable amount of CPU. As you can see, in this specific scenario.

- The application active connection count is very low as we respond to the user with the token as soon as we get the request.
- CPU usage will look normal as we do calculations 2 by 2

Considering these facts, with the load balancer routing we are facing a problem of elastic instances terminating before the full queue is finished calculating and the queue grows really long as the load balancer does not have any idea about the queued requests.

To solve it, either we need to do routing manually, or we need to find a way to let the load balancer know the queued request count (maybe with an API call). If you have an idea of how to do this please help me. (I'm new to AWS)

Any idea is welcome.

Comment: Why would the instances be terminating if there are jobs in the queue? This does not seem right.

Comment: We have an alarm to remove (terminate) the oldest instance if the average CPU usage is less than 20%. By any chance, if the load balancer removed an instance with 100 calculations in the queue (the queue is defined inside the instance), the instance will be active for another 30 minutes and terminate.  At that point is AWS intelligent to know the active processors going on ? (I'm not sure about that)

Comment: Woudn't it be better to manage your autoscaling based on the depth of the queue as shown for example [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-using-sqs-queue.html#scale-sqs-queue-custom-metric)?

Comment: This looks like a what I'mlookung for. I'll give it a try. Thank you !!!

Comment: Glad to hear. If you don't mind I can put it as an answer with some extra info for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

An issue observed with the original approach was **premature termination** of instances since they their scale-in/out is based on CPU utilization only.

A proposed solution to rectify the issue based the scaling activities on the **length of the job queue**. En example of such a solution is shown in the following AWS link:

- [Using Target Tracking with the Right Metric](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-using-sqs-queue.html#scale-sqs-queue-custom-metric)

In the example, the scaling is based on the following metric:

> The solution is to use a **backlog per instance** metric with the target value being the acceptable backlog per instance to maintain.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you !!

Comment: @MudithaPerera No problem. Glad I could help :-)